# How to remove Y-Axis completely from CanavasJS chart

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, jsfiddle, canvasjs

I am using a canvasJS chart and I would like to completely remove/hide Y-Axis.
Here is a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saadtufail/kzmj10qc/3/) example in which I have been able to remove Y-Axis line and Title.
I found the below properties to hide Title and remove line however I am not able to remove the Values on Y-Axis.

```
lineThickness: 0,
gridThickness: 0,
tickThickness: 0
```

However I would like to also remove the data i.e Numbers from 0 to 90.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, labelFontSize:0 seems working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your requirements by setting [labelFormatter](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/label-formatter/). When you set [labelFontSize](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/labelfontsize/) to 0, labels will still occupy some space which is not the case with labelFormatter. The case is same when you use [tickThickness](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/tickthickness/) - instead you can set [tickLength](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/ticklength/) to 0.

Please find the updated code below:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   backgroundColor: "transparent",
   axisX:{
   lineThickness: 0,
   tickLength: 0,
   labelFormatter: function(e) {
       return "";
   }
  },
  axisY:{
   lineThickness: 0,
   gridThickness: 0,
   tickLength: 0,
   labelFormatter: function(e) {
       return "";
   }
  },
  data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55 },
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14 }
      ]
  }]
});

chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
```